# Non azure NLP with Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: c#, nlp, chatbot

I am creating Chatbot using Microsoft Bot framework with C#. For Natural language processing Microsoft suggests using Azure services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Is it possible to use any open-source libraries for NLP without Azure and can integrate with Chatbot built in Microsoft Chatbot?